# yticklabels on the opposite axis

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the yticklabels of a figure made with imshow on the opposite axis. Also I need to set the ticklabels so what I need to control over this axis. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.imshow(...)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelright=True, labelleft=False)
```

Comment: this's an interesting call but is there one for the yticklabels?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited the answer with the correct solution.

Comment: this moves everything, not just the tickslabels. I wonder if there is a way just to shift the labels to the otherside without moving the ticks as well?

Comment: ok, another try - I modified the answer again. check whether this works for you.

Comment: Great this works perfectly! Tell me, where did yo find this information? I looked around in the ax.yaxis attributes but didn't see this. Also searched the docs but came up empty. Can you enlighten me please?

Comment: sure. check out the source code of `ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position` and then you can guess what `set_tick_params` do